# Android application supporting multiple screens?

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to build an android application, the problem is that I want four ImageButtons to cover all the width of the screen.So my question is for differents screens size what dimension my images should be?
For example, in a device with 4 inch screen what should the size of each one of my images be?

Comment: Use .9 image refer https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html.

Comment: show screen shot what you really want and also add some code too how you are doing it right now?

Comment: Use LinearLayout with orientation horizontal and set weight for each imageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.This will equally divide the screen width with 4 image Views.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/img1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/img2" />
       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/img3" />
      <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/img4" />
 </LinearLayout>
```